# glClear function: Question about the parameters

Tags: c, memory, opengl, bit

I would like to understand the glClear function to its profound level. I understand its general explanation -> clear the buffers for color, depth, stencil and accumulation, but I have additional questions. 
My friend assumed that you clear the bits that represent the color, depth, stencil and accumulation in the memory (stack?). By specifying and applying the parameters: (eg. only color and depth) 'masks', you clear only those bits in the memory (hence 'bitwise operation').

Take the example:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Explanation of the parameters by www.khronos.org of "mask".
mask: Bitwise OR of masks that indicate the buffers to be cleared.

Here are my questions:

- Are the parameters GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT and GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT representing 1 bit of memory each? Or how many bits are they represented by (I'd like to understand how the bit mask is actually applied)?
- I don't see how the "OR" mask can cancel bits? If you use "OR" on a bit that is flagged "set" (instead of "unset"), it will still return zero (1 OR 0 still returns 1)? Do I see this entirely wrong / am I missing something here?
- What is up with the "or" sign (pipe); why are these parameters not separated by a usual comma and isn't the bitwise operation "OR" just declared in the actual function?

Perhaps I am confusing things, as I am new in this field. 
Could you please provide me an exhaustive explanation? I prefer not to skip these questions as I move on in OpenGL; I want to know what I am doing and having this understanding may help me along the way. Thanks!

Comment: This is not really related to OpenGL. What going on is, that this is a so called bitfield mask, a technique widely used in C programs, to specify a set of not mutually exclusive options/tasks in a single call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way of writing things permits more flexibility when you're specifying what you want to clear. Here how the flags could be defined:

```
#define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT 1 // 0000 0001
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT 2 // 0000 0010
```

As you can see, those are power of 2. This way, in memory only one bit is set to 1 for each flag (at different positions, obviously).
When you're computing a bitwise OR on those flags, you get 0000 0011. To know if a flag is set in the resulting value, you just need to compute a bitwise AND with the checked flag.

```
int foo = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT; // foo = 0000 0011

if (foo & GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) { // 0000 0011 & 0000 0001 => 0000 0001 (!= 0)
    // clear color buffer(which is located at a position OpenGL knows)
}
if (foo & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) { // 0000 0011 & 0000 0010 => 0000 0010 (!= 0)
    // clear depth buffer
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's clear now! I don't think that I would have figured that out on my own!

Answer (score 3):

The bitwise combination you give to glClear are not the bits that the buffers are cleared with. The buffer are cleared indivually with their specific clear color (glClearColor) or clear depth value (glClearDepth, I think?). The bitwise flags for glClear only tell it what buffers to clear. These are ored bitwise to simply specify more than one buffer to clear.

**EDIT:** You can *imagine* it to work like:

```
void glClear(unsigned int bits)
{
    if(bits & GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)    //color bit is set
    {
        //clear color buffer using current clear color
    }
    if(bits & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)    //depth bit is set
    {
        //clear depth buffer using current clear depth value (usually 1)
    }
    if(bits & GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)  //stencil bit is set
    {
        //clear stencil buffer using current clear stencil value (usually 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: So... what actually happens down there behind the scenes? Could you provide some type of illustration? My bad, but I don't understand it yet... the explanation I found about the bitwise "or" is the following: (Bitwise OR) sets a bit to 1 if one or both of the corresponding bits in its operands are 1, and to 0 if both of the corresponding bits are 0. I cannot fit the explanation in this story...

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, those `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and related bit masks have nothing to do with the eventual clear values written to various buffers.  Each is simply a flag that `glClear()` checks internally (using bitwise AND as others have pointed out) to decide which buffers to act on.

Once the buffer flags have been checked, conceptually, `glClear()` just loops over every pixel in the frame buffer and sets it to the "clear" value so you have a blank slate to draw on.  Those values are set with `glClearColor()` and the like.  You might imagine it like this:

```
void glClear(GLuint buffers)
{
  if (buffers & GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        colorBuffer[i][j].r = clearColor.r;
        colorBuffer[i][j].g = clearColor.g;
        colorBuffer[i][j].b = clearColor.b;
        colorBuffer[i][j].a = clearColor.a;
      }
    }
  }

  if (buffers & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) {
    // Etc, using depthBuffer and glClearDepth value instead here
  }

  // etc. for accum & aux buffers.
}
```

Comment: If you feel the need to supply another answer, which shows the conceptual loop of the actual clear code, then please don't forget the alpha component.

Comment: Is that really how the clear is executed? Isn't this possibly kind of slow... ? Thanks

Comment: @Christian Rau:  Added alpha.  I added my answer b/c it wasn't clear the OP understood that the bit masks had nothing to do with the actual clear values.  Just wanted to be more explicit.  If you add a similar clarification to your answer, I'll be happy to take mine down.

Comment: @user917467:  Really?  Almost certainly not.  It will most likely be a heavily parallelized bitblt at the driver level, but conceptually that's what it does.  Agreed that if this were the actual implementation it would be agonizingly slow.